# Unable to execute a DXL script within DOORS

Tags: ibm-doors

I am using IBM DOORS 9.6 and I aim to develop some DXL code to implement addons.
I have read all the documentation and I have analysed several examples on the web.
But for some reasons, none of the scripts I have tried so far execute successfully. Yet, everything seems fine. I can't say if the error comes from something I miss or from the installation. I have reinstalled DOORS several times, checking that all required options were enabled.
Here is an example of code that fails:

```
// Define a new menu
Menu eCollabMenu = menu("eCollab")

// Define actions for each menu item
void loginAction(Menu m) {
    print "Login action triggered\n"
}

void pushAction(Menu m) {
    print "Push action triggered\n"
}

void pullAction(Menu m) {
    print "Pull action triggered\n"
}

// Create menu items and assign actions
MenuItem miLogin = menuItem("Login", loginAction)
MenuItem miPush = menuItem("Push", pushAction)
MenuItem miPull = menuItem("Pull", pullAction)

// Add items to the menu
add(eCollabMenu, miLogin)
add(eCollabMenu, miPush)
add(eCollabMenu, miPull)

// Attach the menu to the main menu bar
addMenu(eCollabMenu)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.
Regards.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "successfully"? any error messages? Did the admins give you the right to "Edit DXL"?  And: where did you get this code? The types "Menu" and "MenuItem" do not exist in DOORS DXL.  The DXL Reference Manual mentions the commands `createMenu` and `createItem`

Comment: I mean that I got errors on each line of this code. It's like all the syntax is wrong. I have executed the script as admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes, almost all the syntax **is** wrong, as neither the types `Menu` nor `MenuItem` exist in DXL AFAIK.

There is a section "Module menus" in the DXL manual which explains the details. Also, look at the instructions and the example created by Tony Goodman at http://www.smartdxl.com/content/?p=432.

Note that a menu item in DOORS is never a call to a function (like `loginAction` in your example), but a reference to an existing DXL file which contains the code to be executed.

I prefer the method to start DOORS with parameters `-addins <path/to/ModuleExplorerMenus> -projectaddins <path/to/DBExplorerMenus>` and prepare the menu structure as IBM suggests in https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-add-custom-menu-doors-modules